# How to toggle button colour when it is clicked and change the colour back to its previous colour when it is clicked again

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to make a button that is used for starring messages. Initially the colour of the button is white, when I click on the button it should change the colour to golden and when clicking the same button again(unstarring messages), the colour should change the colour again to the initial background colour i:e white.

HTML:
`<button class="btn-hold" data-text-swap=" Starred!">Star Message!</button>`

JavaScript(for toggling the messages on the button):

```
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (button.getAttribute("data-text-swap") == button.innerHTML) {
    button.innerHTML = button.getAttribute("data-text-original");
  } else {
    button.setAttribute("data-text-original", button.innerHTML);
    button.innerHTML = button.getAttribute("data-text-swap");
  }
}, false);
```

CSS:

```
.btn-hold{

    float: right;
    text-decoration-color: white;
    background-color: ; 
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;    
}
button{
    float: right;
}
button:focus{
    background:#FFD700;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the native `toggle` method of the [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) property. Also missing from your `JavaScript` is a reference to the clicked `button`.

```js
var button = document.querySelector('.btn-hold');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.classList.toggle('btn-alt-color');

  if (button.getAttribute("data-text-swap") == button.innerHTML) {
    button.innerHTML = button.getAttribute("data-text-original");
  } else {
    button.setAttribute("data-text-original", button.innerHTML);
    button.innerHTML = button.getAttribute("data-text-swap");
  }
}, false);
```

```css
.btn-hold {
  float: right;
  text-decoration-color: white;
  background-color: ;
  font-family: Lato;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button {
  float: right;
}

button:focus {
  background: #FFD700;
}

.btn-hold.btn-alt-color {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-hold" data-text-swap=" Starred!">Star Message!</button>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b3c8pLo5/2/)

Comment: @MrJ Surely, you jest.

Comment: @MrJ Okay, yeah—I agree, but didn't want to go down the refactoring road. Tempting, though.

Comment: I think it is better to show the code cleaned, we are all in learning

Comment: @MrJ I was really on the fence with this one, but totally see your point.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `element.classList.toggle` returns a Boolean value, no need to make things  complicated :

```js
var
  button           = document.querySelector('.btn-hold'),
  defaultButtonTxt = button.textContent;


button.onclick = function() {
  this.textContent = (this.classList.toggle('btn-alt-color')) ? this.dataset.textSwap : defaultButtonTxt;
}
```

```css
button {
  float: right;
}
.btn-hold {
  float: right;
  text-decoration-color: white;
  background: #FFD700;
  font-family: Lato;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-alt-color {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-hold" data-text-swap=" Starred!">Star Message!</button>
```